# React with Redux: is there a way to sync the "same" components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component named 'RegistrationForm'.

So, now there is a scenario, where desktop layout and mobile layout is different.

Example:

The mobile one:

```
<div className="registration mobile">
    <RegistrationForm/>
</div>
```

The desktop one:

```
 <div className="registration desktop">
     <RegistrationForm/>
 </div>
```

The issue here is that mobile and desktop are placed in a different file due to the design provided. 
So i am thinking, is there a way, to sync the states in all the RegistrationForm? Since technically, if i really have to put two components, it will be treated as independent component, while in reality these two components are like a switch. Only one version will appear at any time.

Comment: so, to clarify, literally the only difference is the class desktop and mobile?

Comment: Nope..
They are located in different files due to the layout difference.
@patrick

Comment: Alright, well that does seem like somewhat of a "smell". Nevertheless, you can achieve what you're asking by using Redux to manage the form state. A library which may provide a good example of this is `redux-form`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below to change the css but have the same component

```
   <div className={`registration ${conditionForMobile?'mobile':'desktop'}`}>
<RegistrationForm/>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm. This one does not solve my issue, because mine is in the same component

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

**1st. You can connect both layouts to redux state**

```
....
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = (yourGlobalState) => {
    return ({ data: yourGlobalState.stateOfForm });
};

export const Mobile = connect(mapStateToProps)(MobileLayout);
export const Desctop = connect(mapStateToProps)(DesctopLayout);
```

Also you can use decorators

```
@connect(mapStateToProps)
export class MobileLayout extends React.Component {
    ....
}
```

**2nd. You can create higher layer to keep state for both layouts.** 
This layer will get the state either by `connect` (like in 1st way) or from another components.

```
....
export class HigherLayer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { data, isMobile } = this.props;
        const Widget = isMobile ? Mobile : Desctop;

        return <Widget data={data}/>;
    }
}
....
```

There is a doc about this approach https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Also you may try to use high order components (HOC) or this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcVAq3YFiuc